# Google's Rich Snippets testing tool error message: "Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org." What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html

Here is my specific coding:

Item 
type: http://schema.org/product 
property:
offers: If this is a gift, and the recipient asks for the sender's identity, may we share this information with them? YES NO The product you selected is currently unavailable. 
image: http://www.kaboodlegifts.com/i/CollegeFirePits/F410_Alabama_LS_shot_LR.jpg 
name: Alabama Crimson Tide Fire Pit Grill 
description:  U of Alabama Crimson Tide Fire Pit Grill. 
 FREE SHIPPING! 
 Roll Tide! 
 Get all fired up with a University of Alabama Crimson Tide... 
url: /catalog/item/8845809/9971405.htm

Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.

Can anyone point this novice in the right direction of how I can fix this? Help is greatly appreciated before I turn completely grey. ;)

Comment: I see within the coding "The product you selected is currently unavailable" BUT it IS available and NOT out of stock.

Comment: Thank you, @daviddeering! Let me try this display: [Item 
type: http://schema.org/product property: offers: If this is a gift, and the recipient asks for the sender's identity, may we share this information with them? YES NO image:http://www.kaboodlegifts.com/i/CollegeFirePits/F410_Alabama_LS_shot_LR.jpg name: Alabama Crimson Tide Fire Pit Grill description: <font color="#000000" size="2" face="verdana"> U of Alabama Crimson Tide Fire Pit Grill. <BR> FREE SHIPPING!url: /catalog/item/8845809/9971405.htm 
Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is being caused due to the offers property and the Offer itemtype being incorrectly nested due to your use of div tags.  Currently, it looks like this:

```
<div itemprop="offers">             
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" style="display:none;">
```

Whereas, it should look something like this:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<various offer properties here...>
</div>
```

On another note, Google's guidelines prohibit hiding your markups with methods such as "display:none" or the use of all meta tags.  So you might want to consider changing that as well.

I hope this helps.

David